# What does it mean when a variable or method or constants has preceded with an underscore in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, naming-conventions

What does it mean in Ruby when you see methods or variables with an underscore before them like this in Rails

```
submit_tag _('Enroll')
:notice => _('Update card.')
```

or

```
_session_id
```

Are most of these just conventions, or do they imply a functional difference in the behavior of the variables/methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in bahavior. It is just convertion.

But let's have a closer look:

`_('A string')` is actually a method not a variable. The underscore method is defined by Gettext and translates a string.

`@_foo` is offen used to show other developers that there is something special about the variable, and therefore it should not be used. I saw that pattern a lot for variables that are used to cache values, like:

```
def expensive_operation
  @_expensive_operation ||= begin
    # long running code...
  end
end
```

And the underscore is sometimes used to indicate that a variable is not used in a block. Like this:

```
a_hash.each do |_, value|
  # do something with the value,  not with the key
end
```

Comment: ...and the last could also be `|_not_using_the_key_here, value|`, though I don't recall seeing that form here at SO...

Answer (score 0):

Those two cases are *completely* different.

The second looks like it is a local variable (although it might be a method call, it's impossible to tell without the context). Local variables that begin with an underscore will not generate an "unused variable" warning if they are unused, which is why they are used to indicate a variable that is *intentionally* not used (as opposed to a typo or pogramming error).

The first is a call to a method named `_`. What this method does, depends on the class of `self` at that point, you will have to look at the documentation for that class.

In IRb, `_` is a method that returns the result of the last expression that was evaluated.